# Position of header, footer and Navigation bar

Tags: php, navigation, footer

I know that header and footer are added using Include in PHP. 
But do we have to set the position of the header and footer? or it is done automatically?

And what if I need to include a navigation bar at the left side of the website??

Like in HTML, we use frame and frameset where we use pixels to divide the content!
So how is it done in PHP?

I ll just take an example.
Index:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include("header.php"); 
Welcome
include("footer.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Nav:

```
echo '<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">';
echo 'Username:';
echo '<input type="text" name="username" /> <br />';
echo 'Password:';
echo '<input type="password" name="password" /> <br />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />';
echo '</form>';
```

I want to Nav to be static.!

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: what you mean by position ? Can you let us know briefly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean it should be static! at the left side! like Facebook!
@Colourity I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are seeking to position a div.

Your PHP code is only used to display (echo) your html code. The way the html code is going to be displayed is determined by your CSS not by PHP.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

As long as i understood your question// here is your ans

you can make static anything you want .. just include another file inside your file ..

i mean if you want your form code static .. then you can add it into your header.php file or anywhere ..

Comment: Yaa! I knw that! But what about Navigation?
As a include header.php, I will also include nav.php!
Then what should I do?? that it will be appear to the left side!?

Comment: you can create navigation.php file and can include it .. even you can include it inside your header.php file as well

Comment: create navigation.php file .. write some code. . and include it inside your header.php file . . i hope this concludes your confusion. let me know if not.

Comment: choose it as best answer if this helps you dear :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a parent layout that includes all of your elements. You have to specify where they must be included as this is not done automatically.

```
//parent layout example
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <?php include("header.php"); ?>
      <div id="container">
         <?php if (//check if you need sidebar here) {
            include("sidebar.php");
         } ?>

         <?php include("content.php"); ?>
      </div>
      <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also nest them as in this example:

```
//header.php example here
<header>
   <img src="your/awesome/logo.png" />
   <?php include("nav.php"); ?>
</header>
```

**Edit:**
I see you're looking for how to display your elements on the page. This is done by CSS and it has nothing to do with PHP.